# Basic less styling not applying to angular directive element

Tags: html, css, angularjs, less, pug

I have the following directive, 'icon':

```
myApp.directive('icon', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
                elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Along with a jade file that uses said directive, like so:

```
icon(ng-click='foo()')
    h1 Some stuff
    p Some other stuff
```

And I have the following less file that styles the element `icon`:

```
icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

For whatever reason, these styles aren't being applied to my directive. This isn't a problem with compiling the less file or the directive -- if I restrict the directive to classes with `restrict: 'C'`, and change the jade file to use the icon class with `.icon(ng-click='foo()')`, as well as change the less file to specify `.icon { ... }`, then everything works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm pretty stumped at the moment.

Comment: I guess `.icon` would work because Jade maybe creates a `div` tag with class as `icon`. `div` is a block element so height and width will apply. Can you try adding `display: block` to your CSS? Also, is `icon` a valid HTML tag?

Comment: Adding `display: block` worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Harry the concept of "valid HTML tags" has been "deprecated" since HTML5, and even more with the new WebComponents API. Also, you could post your comment as a answer if it worked for the OP :)

Comment: @gustavohenke: Thanks for reminding mate. Initially I wanted to assert Jade's behavior before adding as answer but then forgot totally :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jade markup provided in the question would essentially get compiled as shown below:

**Jade markup:**

```
icon(ng-click='foo()')
    h1 Some stuff
    p Some other stuff
```

**Compiled HTML:**

```
<icon ng-click="foo()">
  <h1>Some stuff</h1>
  <p>Some other stuff</p>
</icon>
```

Height and width apply only to block level elements. Since the `icon` is a non-standard tag, the browser would not know whether it has to be rendered as a block level element or an inline element (or inline-block). The browser has to be specifically instructed to display it as a block level element and this can be done by setting the `display` property to `block` using CSS.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/zGIrD)

---

Converting the Jade markup to

```
.icon(ng-click='foo()')
    h1 Some stuff
    p Some other stuff
```

and using the class selector (`.icon`) to specify the properties in CSS would work because of the way Jade works. In Jade, whenever you do not provide a tag name and provide only the class, it is assumed to be a `div` tag. `div` being a standard tag, the browser would know that it is a block level element and hence would apply the defined CSS properties.

**Compiled HTML:** (for the markup using `.icon` class)

```
<div ng-click="foo()" class="icon">
  <h1>Some stuff</h1>
  <p>Some other stuff    </p>
</div>
```

**Quoting [Jade - Language Reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/):**

> Since div's are such a common choice of tag, it is the default if you omit the tag name